# Nontrivial functions $f$ and $g$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Give an example of two nontrivial functions $f$ and $g$ such that $$(f \circ g)(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$$

where $f(x)=$ ?  and $g(x)=$ ?

My answer is $f(x)=\mathrm{sqrt}(x)$ and $g(x)=x^2-1$. But this seems to not be the right answer? Help please.

Comment: It looks fine to me; what do you think the answer is supposed to be?

Comment: The answer you give is the reasonable answer.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is not correct? I mean, because it actually is.

Comment: Cheers! I guess the system wasn't accepting my answer that time, its all good now. Thanks all!

Comment: Your answer is correct. While there are other correct answers, yours is almost certainly the simplest.  Why do you think it is incorrect?  Suggestion: it is less confusing if you write "$f(u) = \sqrt{u}$".  Perhaps "the system" forced you to use "$f(x)$".  But everything you did is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours works just fine (as you've discovered), but it's worth noting that there are **many** other ways we could define such $f,g$. The simplest alternative is probably $f(x)=\sqrt{x-1}$ and $g(x)=x^2,$ but for any real $r$, the functions $f(x)=\sqrt{x+r-1}$ and $g(x)=x^2-r$ will also do the job.

Comment: Oh i see awesome! Thanks again